# What is SiLabsUSBDriver.kext?

Tags: macos

What is SiLabsUSBDriver.kext? Is this part of the official Yosemite system and if so, how do you know? Where can someone go to find this out from Apple directly? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the kernel extension for the Silicon Labs USB to Serial driver.

It is not a part of OS X Yosemite as it's not included in the Install OS X Yosemite.app bundle.

Comment: So... NOT part of Yosemite, then...?

Comment: No it's not and I edited my answer to reflect that fact.  Also the USB2Serial dongle may just have the Silicon Labs chipset and was installed by another product named dongle using that brand chipset.

Comment: Yeah, I think it came from a Garmin GPS install.